# Connecting to user email with oauth2

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to send emails via user account (with out him having to insert user, password) using Oauth2 for connection.

This is my code for getting an access token:

```
String SCOPES =  "https://mail.google.com/";
token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(m_context,SystemUtills.getUsername(m_context)+"@gmail.com","oauth2:" + SCOPES);
```

This works well and gives me a token.

Now I am trying to connect to imap and smtp like this:

```
public class OAuth2Authenticator   extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
private static final Logger logger =Logger.getLogger(OAuth2Authenticator.class.getName());
private static String user_email;
public static final class OAuth2Provider extends Provider {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public OAuth2Provider() {
  super("Google OAuth2 Provider", 1.0,
        "Provides the XOAUTH2 SASL Mechanism");
  put("SaslClientFactory.XOAUTH2",
      "com.google.code.samples.oauth2.OAuth2SaslClientFactory");

}
}

 public static void initialize() {
Security.addProvider(new OAuth2Provider());
}

public static IMAPStore connectToImap(String host,
                                    int port,
                                    String userEmail,
                                    String oauthToken,
                                    boolean debug) throws Exception {
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms.oauth2.oauthToken", oauthToken);
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
session.setDebug(debug);

final URLName unusedUrlName = null;
IMAPSSLStore store = new IMAPSSLStore(session, unusedUrlName);
final String emptyPassword = "";
store.connect(host, port, userEmail, emptyPassword);
return store;
}


public static SMTPTransport connectToSmtp(String host,
                                        int port,
                                        String userEmail,
                                        String oauthToken,
                                        boolean debug) throws Exception {
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms.oauth2.oauthToken", oauthToken);
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
session.setDebug(debug);

final URLName unusedUrlName = null;
SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(session, unusedUrlName);
// If the password is non-null, SMTP tries to do AUTH LOGIN.
final String emptyPassword = "";
transport.connect(host, port, userEmail, emptyPassword);

return transport;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) 
{
    try
    {
        IMAPStore imapStore = connectToImap("imap.gmail.com", 993, AppSettings.user_email,AppSettings.getAccessToken(), true);
        SMTPTransport smtpTransport = connectToSmtp("smtp.gmail.com",587,AppSettings.user_email,AppSettings.getAccessToken(),true);
        return "SUC";
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "FLD";
    }
}
```

In my calling class I am invoking the connection using:

```
new AsyncGetAccessToken().execute();

    OAuth2Authenticator.initialize();
    try{

        new OAuth2Authenticator().execute();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For the smtp (debug negotiation:

```
04-01 07:57:08.770: I/System.out(31190): DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.1
04-01 07:57:37.890: I/System.out(31190): DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
04-01 07:57:37.900: I/System.out(31190): DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587,  isSSL false
04-01 07:57:38.150: I/System.out(31190): 220 mx.google.com ESMTP q41sm37770244eez.7 - gsmtp
04-01 07:57:38.150: I/System.out(31190): DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587
04-01 07:57:38.155: I/System.out(31190): EHLO localhost
04-01 07:57:38.310: I/System.out(31190): 250-mx.google.com at your service, [46.120.129.170]
04-01 07:57:38.310: I/System.out(31190): 250-SIZE 35882577
04-01 07:57:38.320: I/System.out(31190): 250-8BITMIME
04-01 07:57:38.320: I/System.out(31190): 250-STARTTLS
04-01 07:57:38.320: I/System.out(31190): 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
04-01 07:57:38.320: I/System.out(31190): 250 CHUNKING
04-01 07:57:38.330: I/System.out(31190): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
04-01 07:57:38.330: I/System.out(31190): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
04-01 07:57:38.330: I/System.out(31190): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
04-01 07:57:38.335: I/System.out(31190): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
04-01 07:57:38.335: I/System.out(31190): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
04-01 07:57:38.345: I/System.out(31190): STARTTLS
04-01 07:57:38.440: I/System.out(31190): 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
04-01 07:57:39.115: I/System.out(31190): EHLO localhost
04-01 07:57:39.220: I/System.out(31190): 250-mx.google.com at your service, [46.120.129.170]
04-01 07:57:39.220: I/System.out(31190): 250-SIZE 35882577
04-01 07:57:39.220: I/System.out(31190): 250-8BITMIME
04-01 07:57:39.225: I/System.out(31190): 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
04-01 07:57:39.225: I/System.out(31190): 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
04-01 07:57:39.225: I/System.out(31190): 250 CHUNKING
04-01 07:57:39.235: I/System.out(31190): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
04-01 07:57:39.235: I/System.out(31190): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
04-01 07:57:39.240: I/System.out(31190): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN"
04-01 07:57:39.240: I/System.out(31190): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
04-01 07:57:39.245: I/System.out(31190): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
04-01 07:57:39.245: I/System.out(31190): DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
04-01 07:57:39.250: I/System.out(31190): AUTH LOGIN
04-01 07:57:39.350: I/System.out(31190): 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
04-01 07:57:39.355: I/System.out(31190): bWljaGFlbC5hc2FyYWZAZ21haWwuY29t
04-01 07:57:39.460: I/System.out(31190): 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
04-01 07:57:39.470: I/System.out(31190): 
04-01 07:57:39.990: I/System.out(31190): 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
04-01 07:57:39.990: I/System.out(31190): 535 5.7.8 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257    q41sm37770244eez.7 - gsmtp
```

And an exception:

```
04-01 08:00:57.860: W/System.err(31190): javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
04-01 08:00:57.880: W/System.err(31190):        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
04-01 08:00:57.885: W/System.err(31190):        at com.my_android_assistant.OAUTH.OAuth2Authenticator.connectToSmtp(OAuth2Authenticator.java:128)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not using the OAuth2 provider because the server advertises LOGIN so JavaMail chooses that first.  You need to disable the LOGIN and PLAIN mechanisms to force it to use SASL and choose XOAUTH2.  Set "mail.imaps.auth.login.disable" and "mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable" to "true".

Also, you might want to try the [OAuth2 support built into JavaMail 1.5.2](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2).  A [SNAPSHOT release](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Development_Releases) is available.

Comment: That sounds good thanks (ill try it later). One more thing in prior version of my code i used java mail to send mail using the user pass (askingg him for credentials). if i understant correct you are saying that i can use the java.mail 1.5.2 with the OAUTH token insteat of the password and just use my prior code?